# Confused on the output of 'ip addr show'

Tags: unix, cmd

I am trying to retrieve the ipaddress of the unix system.. ip addr show..

and I got this as an output

```
2: eth0:  mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:ac:6f:65:31:e5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.100/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::baac:6fff:fe65:31e5/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

But I am not clear on the output So can anyone help me in finding
what can be the Ip address in the above data ?

Comment: This is not a programming question. Try http://s.tk/unix

Comment: Voted to move to ServerFault. However, if the output of `ip addr show` doesn't make sense, use `ifconfig` instead. The formatting would be a little easier to understand for you, as it's more clearly delimited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 2: eth0:  mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
>       link/ether b8:ac:6f:65:31:e5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
>       inet **192.168.2.100**/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global eth0
>       inet6 **fe80::baac:6fff:fe65:31e5**/64 scope link
>          valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

ipv4 and ipv6

Answer (score 1):

ARPing for Local vs. Remote IP Addresses = command arp -a